# stopping a server side function in c#

Tags: c#, javascript

my code :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Search" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text='<%$Resources:Strings,Search %>' OnClick="Search_Click"  />
```

server side :

```
protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var script = "CheckIfItemSelected()";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "MyScript", script, true);
}
```

client side :

```
function CheckIfItemSelected() {
        var SalesmanSelectedItem = $find('<%= SalesmanGrid_grd.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().get_selectedItems().length;
        var ProductsSelectedItem = $find('<%= SalsemanProductsGrid_grd.ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().get_selectedItems().length;

        if (SalesmanSelectedItem == 0 && ProductsSelectedItem == 0) {

            $("#<%=ErrorMsg.ClientID %>").html("please select a salesman at least<br>please select a product at least");
            return false;
        }
        if (SalesmanSelectedItem == 0) {
            $("#<%=ErrorMsg.ClientID %>").html("please select a salesman at least");
            return false ;
        }
        if (ProductsSelectedItem == 0) {
            $("#<%=ErrorMsg.ClientID %>").html("please select a product at least");
            return false;
        }
        $("#<%=ErrorMsg.ClientID %>").html("");
        return true;
    }
```

the question is if my client side function return false i want to stop the server side function from continue how should i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my solution i hope it wld help :

```
 protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int SelectedSalesmans=  SalesmanGrid_grd.SelectedItems.Count;
  int SelectedProducts = SalsemanProductsGrid_grd.SelectedItems.Count;
  if (SelectedSalesmans == 0)
  {
      var script = "DisplayErrorMsg(\"Please Choose a salesman AT least. \")";
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "MyScript", script, true);
      return;
  }
  if (SelectedProducts == 0)
  {
      var script = "DisplayErrorMsg(\"Please Choose a Product AT least. \")";
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "MyScript", script, true);
      return;
  }
}
```

client side:

```
function DisplayErrorMsg(msg) {
        $("#<%=ErrorMsg.ClientID %>").html(msg);
    }
```